# new Vue() on every Blade or components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am currently learning Vue.js and Laravel.

Afaik a fresh Vue application is by default created in the app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

So until now I have always created new components and used them in my blade.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

  <add-Participants></add-Participants>
  <my-table></my-table>

@endsection
```

Is this what you are supposed to do or should I rather initialise a new Vue application for every blade?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the `app.js` file in Laravel (and it has been there before Vue was published) and I guess it seems like an obvious choice to bind a Vue instance to an element named `app` for documentation and teaching purposes, but I never saw that as some kind of standard or even default.

Having a whole web app wrapped inside such an element might even cause trouble because sometimes more than one instance of Vue is required, but Vue instances can't be nested (without workarounds or when using components).

Also, remember we're talking about JavaScript, everything happens in the browser and Vue instances on `page1.html`and `page2.html` are separate, even if they inherit some `app` element from the same Blade template.

So I'd say: Do what suits your (app's) needs best.

Comment: So.. how DO I create a Vue app? Whenever I try to create a new one in my blade it either says "require not defined" or "vue not defined"

Comment: The simplest way to import Vue is `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>`. Your mention of "require not defined" makes me suspect you're already importing Vue using NPM, but there's some syntax error or typo in some part of your code that's not in your question.
`